# I don't understand how to work Bower properly

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, bower

I'm building a site and I've decided to use a bootstrap template for the back-end (admin tools and whatnot).

I like the look of sb-admin-2 (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) but I'ma bit confused how to practically employ this in my site.
I installed Bower and installed sb-admin using `bower install startbootstrap-sb-admin-2`

Now I have a folder called bower_components, and it's filled with all the relevant packages... However, these packages include the development files as well.

If I upload this to my site as is, 80% of it will be unnecessary source data.
I'm currently using Gulp with my project, but I don't yet see how the 2 are supposed to interact. Is there a gulp package for compiling the bower_components into 1 concise thing?

I'm new to this kind of workflow and I can't find the answers to the questions despite my efforts. Apologies if I sound like a total noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no pre-built gulp package that will pull in all your bower source files. You should write a task that pulls in just the files you need. Here's an example from a project I'm working on (simplified):

```
var scripts = [
    'bower_components/timezone-js/src/date.js',                             // https://github.com/mde/timezone-js
    'bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js',                                // http://api.jquery.com/
    'bower_components/jquery-migrate/jquery-migrate.js',                    // https://github.com/appleboy/jquery-migrate
    'bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js',              // todo: include just the bits we need
    'bower_components/jqueryui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js',   // https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch
    'bower_components/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js',                      // https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
    'bower_components/jquery.expander/jquery.expander.min.js',              // https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-expander
    'bower_components/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.js',                    // http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/
    'bower_components/select2/select2.min.js',                              // http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
    'bower_components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js',             // http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/
    'bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.min.js',                    // https://lodash.com/docs
    'bower_components/underscore.string/dist/underscore.string.min.js',     // https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#string-functions
    'bower_components/json2/json2.js',                                      // https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
    'bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js',       // http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/
    'bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js',
    'bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js',          // https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
    'bower_components/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js',            // https://datatables.net/
];

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src(scripts, {base: '.'})
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
            loadMaps: false,
            debug: debug,
        }))
        .pipe(concat('all_the_things.js', {
            newLine:'\n;' // the newline is needed in case the file ends with a line comment, the semi-colon is needed if the last statement wasn't terminated
        }))
        .pipe(uglify({
            output: { // http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/codegen
                beautify: debug,
                comments: debug ? true : /^!|\b(copyright|license)\b|@(preserve|license|cc_on)\b/i,
            },
            compress: { // http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress, http://davidwalsh.name/compress-uglify
                sequences: !debug,
                booleans: !debug,
                conditionals: !debug,
                hoist_funs: false,
                hoist_vars: debug,
                warnings: debug,
            },
            mangle: !debug,
            outSourceMap: true,
            basePath: 'www',
            sourceRoot: '/'
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {
            includeContent: true,
            sourceRoot: '/',
        }))
        .pipe(plumber.stop())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/js'))
});
```

I'm cherry-picking the source files I want, combining and minifying them, and dumping them into my public directory so that can be served to the client. You don't need to upload the `bower_components` folder to your production server; but it probably wouldn't hurt much either (it's not THAT big!).

Comment: This is great, but what about all the requires in the bower_component packages? This doesn't appear to automatically include them in the mix.

Comment: @hedgehog90 Most bower components should come with a pre-built version that bundles all the dependencies into one file. Include that one. `require` doesn't work in client-side JS unless you use another tool like Browserify. I'm guessing those `require`s are for the node.js version of the library though.